# creating two sockets at udp server at a time, how to bind()?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-programming, udp

I want two functionalities to be implemented on my udp server application.

1. Creating thread that continuously receives data coming from any client.
2. Creating a thread that continuously sends data on server socket after specific time period and waits for reply from client. (I implemented this to make aure that whenever any client goes down, the data is not received back from client and server comes to know that client is down.)

Now, the problem I am facing is that since two threads are sharing same connected socket, whenever both threads try to access this socket simultaneously, a deadlock is established.

One of the solution I found was to create two sockets. One that continuously receives data, and the other socket that is meant for sending data from server time to time to clients and wait for their response, but since Server can must be bind()ed and I have bind()ed my socket to  INADDR_ANY once, how would I create a separate socket for sending data from server and waiting for replies from client.

Please help me with this complication.

Also do let me know if there is some other better way of its implementation.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [non-blocking net functions](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html) and use a [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes) to ensure no two threads access the socket at once.

A single thread may, however, be enough, if you use non-blocking functions. Using many threads will probably not improve performance, but *may* make the code more readable.

Comment: But I want both of my threads to use Sokcet simultaneously, if I reuse the Address, even then how can I use same address to receive and send data simultaneously? Sorry if I am asking stupid things, actually I am so confused :(

Comment: If you reuse the address, you will probably be able to bind a second socket to the same port and then safely use them separately from threads. But remember, that only the first bound socket will be able to receive data.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I want both of my threads to send and receive data :(

Comment: Yeah, so I completely changed my answer. Use non-blocking read functions and guard the multithreaded access through a mutex.

Comment: what if I make another Socket at Server side with a different IP Address (lets say 172.16.0.0) and on the Client side, for replying back to ACK, client should send data at this specific IP address

Comment: I have created two Sokets on Server side now.
First Socket is bind()ed to INADDR_ANY.
Second Socket is bind()ed to my Machines IP Address.
All sends and receives from client are done on first socket.
The Handshake mechanism to ensure that the client has not gone down is done on the second socket.